# gnuplot svg legend label position

Tags: svg, gnuplot

When I run gnuplot my legend is displayed like this:

[image]

Now I use the menu item "Export to SVG" and save the file. In my svg file, the legend is displayed like this. What is the problem?

[image]

Here is my plot script:

```
set title "my title"
set grid
set xlabel 'my xlabel'
set ylabel 'my ylabel'
set yrange[0:150]
set key left top
plot "BOOST-POP.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) title "BOOST", \
     "LFS-POP.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) title "LFS", \
     "CDS_FC-POP.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) title "CDS\\\_FC", \
     "STL-POP.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) title "STL mit Mutex"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using white spaces in the plot titles? If so, remove them and try to force the legend with the command `set key width 1`, where `width` refers to the distance between the symbols and the titles (negative numbers are also allowed to reduce the standard distance).

PS You can also decide how to align the titles or to put them on the left as explained [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node192.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated my question: Now you can see my plot script. There are no white spaces as you can see... I also tried `set key vertical Right` without success. But I circumvented my problem now by using `set key vertical Left reverse` which switches the position of icons and labels. Now I can use Left without any trouble.

Comment: Good! I know that my answer is not so conclusive so I'm glad to notice that you were able to avoid it. Anyway, it is a very strange behavior of the svg terminal (usually I use just postscript or png, so I never met it).